# In Karate DSL Framework, IntelliJ IDE is unable to find visible feature files using Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gradlew, karate

When using the following tools to create a sample Karate DSL Test; a "no features found at [classpath: packagename]" is thrown:

IntelliJ 2017.2.3
Gradle 2.9

project structure is shown in screenshot. Note that I have used the exact same project structure in Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 with Gradle and I was not able to replicate this issue. I also used Maven with Intellij and this issue did not occur.

The issue is isolated to Intellij using Gradle! any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: please disregard my initial answer which I deleted, I see the problem where you want features in sub-folders to also be loaded. I don't have experience with gradle + intellij so I'll try to refer others I know to look at this SO.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I also tried to add the CucumberOptions and it threw the error again this time being more specific.  @CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:testsuite/library/setup.feature")
No features found at [classpath:testsuite/library/setup.feature]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is IntelliJ Gradle does not honor the [`sourceSets` tweak](https://github.com/intuit/karate#folder-structure) needed for the recommended Karate folder structure.

I just had an idea, try switching to the "traditional" Java project structure where `*.feature` files are in `src/test/resources` (not `src/test/java`) and that might just work.

Example project structure, from IDEA 2017.2.6 with Gradle.

[image: idea-gradle-structure]

Comment: Thanks Peter. Although this solution work, now it is not recognizing one of my java classes. It doesn't make sense to me why this is an issue with IntelliJ but not Eclipse. I decided to use Eclipse moving forward. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I think it's worse than that, IntelliJ Gradle doesn't seem to honour CucumberOptions either... I'll submit another question on this